# Is there a way to get unit coverage percentage (eg from jacoco) on only new code?

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

My hypothethical scenario is this:

- I have run my junit tests and generated a jacoco file
- my git diff shows I have changed 10 lines of code

Now the intersection of my git diff and the jacoco information is that 7 of the 10 lines of code changed are covered. ie - I have 70% coverage on new code.

But I had to work that out manually.

I'd like an automated way to work out the percentage how many new lines of code are covered.

My question is: **Is there a way to get unit coverage percentage (eg from jacoco) on only new code?**

(Note I know [sonarqube](http://sonarqube.org/) can do this if you run the scanner with `analysis.mode=publish` and get interrogate the task result with the JSON API - I'm looking for something lightweight that a developer can run locally.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a read of this:
https://juliangamble.com/blog/2017/09/01/commit-level-coverage-reporting/

Then use this project:
https://github.com/juliangamble/commit-level-coverage-report

Comment: is this available for Gradle as well?

Answer (score 5):

There are two plugins:

- Gradle: [delta coverage gradle plugin](https://github.com/SurpSG/delta-coverage-plugin)
- Maven: [diff coverage maven plugin](https://github.com/SurpSG/diff-coverage-maven-plugin)

Both are built on top of JaCoCo and able to generate JaCoCo like reports.
[image]

Also, they able to fail the build if your coverage ratio is less than expected(the ratio colud be configured by the plugins)

Answer (score 3):

Jacoco + [diff-cover](https://github.com/Bachmann1234/diff_cover)

It is work for me. CI Shell script:

```
export PATH="${jobPath}"/buildbox/Python-3.8.2/bin:$PATH
python --version
python -m pip install -i http://xx.xx.xx.com/artifactory/api/pypi/xx-pypi-public/simple/ --trusted-host xx.xx.xx.com diff_cover==4.0.1

mvn clean test -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

diff-cover "${WORKSPACE}"/xxx-test/target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml --compare-branch origin/"${target_branch}" --src-roots $(find . -name java -type d | grep 'src/main/java$' | egrep -v "target|test|testkit") --html-report ${WORKSPACE}/xxx-test/target/site/jacoco/index.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option without additional plugins is to parse html with regex.

build.gradle part for jacoco:

```
jacocoTestReport {
    dependsOn test
    reports {
        xml.required = true
        csv.required = false
        // This method requires html report to be generated
        html.required = true
    }
}
```

And then you can use sed to parse the report:

```sh
sed -nE 's/^.*<td>Total<([^>]+>){4}([^<]*).*$/Missed instructions: \2/p' build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html
```

Which will print you the percentage from this column:
[image]

For only second column:

```sh
sed -nE 's/^.*<td>Total<([^>]+>){8}([^<]*).*$/Missed branches: \2/p' build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html
```

For both:

```sh
sed -nE 's/^.*<td>Total<([^>]+>){4}([^<]*)([^>]+>){4}([^<]*).*$/First: \2; Second: \4/p' build/reports/jacoco/test/html/index.html
```

Comment: This may do something a bit different from the OP's original question, which was "Is there a way to get unit coverage percentage (eg from jacoco) on only new code?"